# Password field entry -- show *

Tags: tkinter

I want that if someone writes in textbox it should be encrypted.I am using in tkinter Python plz help.

```
self.password=Entry(app)
            self.password.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)
```

For example In password when someone writes "movies" it should be visible like this `******`

Answer (score 3):

It is simple.

`e = Entry(root,show='*')`